# How to get key value pairs in google vision ocr?

Tags: python, ocr, image-recognition, google-vision

I have been using google vision API for retrieving the text from images, the output json file just contains the text and the coordinates of the text. Is there any way we can get key value pairs from google vision ocr?

Comment: Key values pairs of what? Which information are you missing?

Comment: Key value pairs of table data. AWS provide one service called textract document detection it gives all the identified key value pairs like name: something, age something in image. Similarly is there any way that google provides the key value pairs of tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

The way google vision ocr works is that it detects texts in blocks and in paragraphs inside these blocks. Provided your tables are in the same format, you can just manipulate the json output to give you key and value pairs. Aside from this, I do not think google vision ocr can do explicitly, what you're asking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer I just thought may be if there is any service that google provides regarding key value pair. But thanks for your reply.